# When someone clicks "back", how do I get the user to the same position? (PHP)

Tags: javascript

When someone clicks on a link, it sends them to it. But when a user clicks back, i want it to be at the position where they were before. 
What is the name for this and how do I go about doing this?

Like on SO, when I click "back", the scroll bar isn't at the top but rather at the position where I was last.

Comment: are your referring to scrolling? you'd have to capture the position of the scroll using javascript and send it as a get/post/session cookie or session variable of some sort.

Comment: Isn't it the default behavior in the browser?

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with PHP? The topic ought to be browsers and how they handle page anchors (if any; a page anchor = a named position on a page) - and should happen automatically unless you've got JavaScript interfering. Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah I am referring to scrolling. I just didn't know what it was called.

Comment: If it isn't happening, you should see if you have JavaScript interfering. What you're wanting is definitely browser default behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no name for it and nothing you can do to make it happen explicitly, but it happens by itself in most browsers.